Disable website's navbar from expanding on hover to inspect spacing between elements
Sorry for the noob question -
But I'm trying to disable the navbar's menu items from expanding so I can inspect the spacing between the menu and the title div element below it.
If there's any pointers on how I can achieve that through Firefox dev tool would be much appreciated!
I tried to update the dropdown items to display:none on hover and in focus but still can see the expanded child li dropdown items.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

I finally went to my _navBar.js to temporarily disable the child menu items from expanding
export function initNavDropdown () {    
    // inserted a line of "return"
    return
    const headerNavCategory = document.getElementById('header-nav-category')


